# Image is appearing between text when I don't want it to in LaTeX

Tags: graphics

I want my new paragraph to appear below the two image. That is, the second page will have the second image followed by all the text. However, it seems like my code will shift the text in a way that efficiently uses the page instead.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{"Q1 (2) graph1".png}
    \caption{Dynamic response to a reduction in the value of filled jobs}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{"Q1 (2) graph2".png}
    \caption{Dynamic response to a reduction in the value of filled jobs}
\end{figure}

(3) At $t = 1$, a recession caused the matching efficiency parameter $A$ to decrease to $A = 0.3$ for $15$ months...
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you Dr Manuel Kuehner. I am going to ace this macroeconomic assignment now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want my new paragraph to appear below the two image[s].

If you want to assure that no text material will be placed between the two `figure` environments, just create a *single* `figure` environment that contains two `\includegraphics` and two `\caption` statements.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics{"Q1 (2) graph1".png}
\caption{Dynamic response to a reduction in the value of filled jobs}

\vspace{2\baselineskip} % choose a suitable amount of vertical whitespace
\includegraphics{"Q1 (2) graph2".png}
\caption{Dynamic response to a reduction in the value of filled jobs, cont'd}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: +1: Good idea! I think that I never used this before.